Android Module Publication has AAR, source and javadoc jars, but not showing documentation when implementing via build gradle dependencies
The end goal of my issue is to have an Android library module I'm working on generate a release publicationVariant via mavenLocal and eventually github packages via Maven. This publication should be implementable via group, artifactId, and version in a fresh Android project. The implemented aar should also show documentation for the functions and classes that I wrote documentation for.
I've followed multiple SO posts in regards to my issue. I've done everything I could but I cannot seem to get the following key things to work:

The documentation to show whenever I highlight or CMD + CLK on a class to see its source code.
The source and javadoc jars I've written as tasks in the library module's build.gradle to be visible in the gradle cached transform jars  jars directory; I only see classes.jar

The 1st point is the best outcome for me, and I can get it to show provided I select Choose Sources under the source code in the implementing project, select the source/javadoc jar(s) located somewhere else not in my gradle cached sub-directories. But at that point, I would want it to happen automatically on project implement, not requiring me to manually select the sourceJar.
The 2nd point is good too, but like I said above, I cannot find any record of the sources or javadoc jars in the gradle cached folder for the jars under the artifact-id of my library module whenever I try finding it via Choose sources option.
The implementing project for this aar has the one line to import the dependency in build.gradle, and I can confirm it does work in bringing my published library module into the project.
But without documentation, nor access to the build/libs directory in the implementing project, I'm stuck on how to progress. Any help would be appreciated, and if I'm required to rephrase the question to make more sense or more details, I'll do it. Thanks.
